# Calculating difference between dates which are in datarame column, in days using np.where throws invalid type promotion error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas datafrme like this

```
          D1               D2
0
1  3/4/2019 0:00    2/3/2019 0:00
2                   2/4/2019 0:00
```

Column D1 & D2 contains dates. I want to calculate difference between these two dates in days & store it in new column 'DIFF'

```
   D1               D2                 DIFF
0
1  3/4/2019 0:00    2/3/2019 0:00      29
2                   2/4/2019 0:00
```

I use np.where as follows:

```
df['DIFF'] = np.where((df['D1']!='') & (df['D2']!=''),pd.to_datetime(df['D1']) -pd.to_datetime(df['D2']),'')
```

However it is throwing error - Invalid type promotion.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) with convert timedeltas to numeric values and then to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
s = (pd.to_datetime(df['D1']) - pd.to_datetime(df['D2'])).dt.days.astype('Int64')
df['DIFF'] = np.where((df['D1']!='') & (df['D2']!=''), s, '')

print (df)
              D1             D2 DIFF
0                                   
1  3/4/2019 0:00  2/3/2019 0:00   29
2  2/4/2019 0:00
```

Another idea is add `errors='coerce'` to `to_datetime` for possible parsing bad datetimes or empty strings and then set values in `np.where`:

```
s = (pd.to_datetime(df['D1'], errors='coerce') -
     pd.to_datetime(df['D2'], errors='coerce')).dt.days.astype('Int64')

df['DIFF'] = np.where(s.notna(), s, '')

print (df)
            D1             D2 DIFF
0                                   
1  3/4/2019 0:00  2/3/2019 0:00   29
2  2/4/2019 0:00
```